# Space between Bootstrap 3 buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I put several Bootstrap 3 buttons in a row:

```
    <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
```

there is a small space between them. Where does it come from and how to remove it without using float? According to the Firebug and Chrome Inspector the buttons haven't any margin applied to them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The newline between the buttons actually causes the space. Observe:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button><button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button><button class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
```

There **is** a button-group rule you can use if you want the buttons visually grouped: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to avoid the new lines in order to remove this space or there is another way?

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov It's the *simplest* way, and is true for pretty much every set of controls you want to group horizontally. As I noted in my last edit, BS does have a grouping style for buttons, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Actually, if the buttons are floated they don't have this space. It is present only when they are not floated. I want to remove the space between the non-floated buttons and when I apply custom margin all buttons (floated and non-floated) to have equal space between then. Now, thanks to your answer I know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you style your buttons `display:inline-block;` or `inline`. By default they create spaces if you have newline character.

So to remove it, put those markups next to each other without newline char.
It would get messy, but will get what you want without having a style `float`

So do it like this :

```
<button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button><button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button><button class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
```